# How to convert "string" to "timestamp without time zone"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, postgresql, wcf

I am new to Postgresql and I am using WCF services.
Here is my code snippet:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '../Services/AuctionEntryServices.svc/InsertAuctionDetails',
    data: JSON.stringify({ "objAuctionEntryEntity": {
        "AuctionNO": '',          
        "AuctionDate": $('[Id$="lblAuctionDateVal"]').text(),
        "TraderID": $('[Id$="ddlTraderName"] option:selected').val(),
        "Grade": $('[Id$="ddlGrade"] option:selected').val(),
        "Varity": $('[Id$="ddlVarity"] option:selected').val(), 
        "QuntityInAuction": $('#txtQuantityForAuction').val(),
        "AuctionRate": $('#txtAuctionRate').val(),
        "BrokerID": a[0],
        "IsSold": $('#chlIsSold').is(':checked'),
        "CreatedBy": $.parseJSON(GetCookie('Admin_User_In_Mandi')).UserID,
        "UpdatedBy": $.parseJSON(GetCookie('Admin_User_In_Mandi')).UserID,
        "CreationDate": GetCurrentDate().toMSJSON(),
        "IsActive": true,
        "AuctionTransaction": arrAuctionTransaction,
        "MandiID": $.parseJSON(GetCookie('Admin_User_In_Mandi')).MandiID,
        "FarmerID": _ownerid,
        "AuctionNO": _auctionno,
        "AmmanatPattiID": _ammantpattiid,
        "ToTraderID": b[0],
        "ToTraderName": $('#txtOtherBuyerNameEN').val(),
        "ToTraderName_HI": $('#txtOtherBuyerNameHI').val()
    }
}),
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json'              
});
```

Here:

```
$('[Id$="lblAuctionDateVal"]').text() = "20/8/2013 14:52:49"
```

And my data type for this field is `timestamp without time zone`.
How to convert this string to `timestamp without time zone` data type?

Comment: Have you checked the to_timestamp() function? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-formatting.html

Answer (score 53):

String representation of a `timestamp` (= `timestamp without time zone`) depends on your locale settings. Therefore, to avoid ambiguities leading to data errors or Postgres coughing up an exception, you have two options:

**1.)** Use [**ISO 8601 format**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-DATE-TABLE), which works the same with *any* locale or [`DateStyle`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-DATESTYLE) setting:

```
'2013-08-20 14:52:49'
```

You may have to cast the string literal explicitly where the data type cannot be derived from context, depending on the use case:

```
'2013-08-20 14:52:49'::timestamp
```

**2.)** Convert the string to `timestamp` using [**`to_timestamp()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html) with a matching template pattern:

```
to_timestamp('20/8/2013 14:52:49', 'DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mi:ss')
```

This returns `timestamptz`, assuming the current timezone setting. Typically (like in an assigmment) the type is coerced accordingly. For `timestamp`, this means that the time offset is truncated and you get the expected value.
Again, if the target type cannot be derived from context, you may have to cast explicitly:

```
to_timestamp('20/8/2013 14:52:49', 'DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mi:ss')::timestamp
```

Since that simply strips the time offset, it results in the expected value. Or use the `AT TIME ZONE` construct with a time zone of your choosing:

```
to_timestamp('20/8/2013 14:52:49', 'DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mi:ss') AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'
```

While the target time zone is the same as your current `timezone` setting, no transformation takes place. Else the resulting timestamp is transposed accordingly. Further reading:

- [Ignoring time zones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-time-zones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170)

Answer (score 31):

To convert a string into a timestamp without timezone, for Postgresql, I use the above

```
SELECT to_timestamp('23-11-1986 09:30:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY hh24:mi:ss')::timestamp without time zone;
```

Comment: hey hello, thanks a lot buddy. I just lost my last 5 hours for searching this .....