# Postgres: Error when using COPY from a CSV with timestamptz type

Tags: postgresql

I am using Postgres 9.5.3(On Ubuntu 16.04) and I have a table with some `timestamptz` fields

```
...
datetime_received timestamptz NULL,
datetime_manufactured timestamptz NULL,
...
```

I used the following SQL command to generate CSV file:

```
COPY (select * from tmp_table limit 100000) TO '/tmp/aa.csv' DELIMITER ';' CSV HEADER;
```

and used:

```
COPY tmp_table FROM '/tmp/aa.csv' DELIMITER ';' CSV ENCODING 'UTF-8';
```

to import into the table.

The example of rows in the CSV file:

```
CM0030;;INV_AVAILABLE;2016-07-30 14:50:42.141+07;;2016-08-06 00:00:000+07;FAHCM00001;;123;;;;;1.000000;1.000000;;;;;;;;80000.000000;;;2016-07-30 14:59:08.959+07;2016-07-30 14:59:08.959+07;2016-07-30 14:59:08.959+07;2016-07-30 14:59:08.959+07;
```

But I encounter the following error when running the second command:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type timestamp with time zone: "datetime_received"
CONTEXT:  COPY inventory_item, line 1, column datetime_received: "datetime_received"
```

My database's timezone is:

```
 show timezone;
 TimeZone  
-----------
 localtime(GMT+7)
(1 row)
```

Is there any missing step or wrong configuration?

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: What do rows in `/tmp/aa.csv` look like ...

Comment: @donkopotamus Edited ;)

Comment: Just a suspicion: change `2016-08-06 00:00:00+07` to `2016-08-06 00:00:00.000+07` on that row and run it again please.

Comment: @JorgeCampos Unfortunately, It does not work.

Comment: Testing here with a simplified table but direct copy of your values, it's loading fine, the date format is ok.  Can you provide your actual table structure (CREATE TABLE statement) please?

Comment: Tested here and the same error occur, maybe this is related? http://stackoverflow.com/a/14042589/460557

Comment: It's trying (and failing) to interpret the string `'datetime_received'` as a timestamp. You forgot to tell `COPY FROM` to ignore the header.

Comment: @NickBarnes You are right, post an answer now ;)

Comment: @NickBarnes Please post an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're seeing means that Postgres is trying (and failing) to convert the string `'datetime_received'` to a timestamp value.

This is happening because `COPY` is trying to insert the header row into your table. You need to include a `HEADER` clause on the `COPY FROM` command, just like you did for the `COPY TO`.

More generally, when using `COPY` to move data around, you should make sure that the `TO` and `FROM` commands are using exactly the same options. Specifying `ENCODING` for one command and not the other can lead to errors, or silently corrupt data, if your client encoding is not UTF8.