# Removing time part from a timestamp column

Tags: sql, postgresql, types

I am in need of experts' help here. I have a column "Actual_Date" of data type `timestamp`. It is in the format:

```
yyyy - mm - dd 00:00:00
```

I want to convert the column into the format:

```
mm - dd - yyyy
```

How can I convert the date?

Comment: timestamp without time zone

Comment: Unrelated, but: you should _really_ avoid quoted identifiers like `"Actual_Date"` they are much more trouble then they are worth it.

Comment: so you want to change the data type of the column to store date only, or you just want to select without time?.. What is behind " convert the column into the format"?..

Comment: You neglected to disclose the *actual* data type of source and target.

Comment: Timestamp without timezone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to format it the way you want using `to_char()`

```
select to_char("Actual_Date", 'mm-dd-yyyy')
from the_table;
```

More details in the manual:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-DATETIME-TABLE

Answer (score 8):

The exact data type matters. If you have a `timestamp` column (`timestamp without time zone`) and want the date part as `date`, just cast:

```
SELECT my_timestamp::date;
```

You can do the same with `timestamptz` (`timestamp with time zone`), the resulting date depends on the time zone setting of your current session, though. The current "date" depends on where in the world you ask ...

Or you can use `to_char()` like [a_horse provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41168922/939860), to get a `text` as result.

If it's just a matter of how date and timestamp are *displayed*, look at the `datestyle` setting:

- [Importing .csv with timestamp column (dd.mm.yyyy hh.mm.ss) using psql \copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14042452/importing-csv-with-timestamp-column-dd-mm-yyyy-hh-mm-ss-using-psql-copy/14042589#14042589)

To get reliable `text` representation, independent of settings, `to_char()` is the safe bet.

Comment: Thanks Erwin, I retrieve my data as timestamp without timezone. Is there anyway I can possibly convert the date format as to mm-dd-yyyy permanently?

Comment: @Pythoner: values for `date` or `timestamp` columns are stored **without** a format. The format is applied when _displaying_ the values. You configure your SQL client if you want to display dates or timestamps in a different way.