# Data type for date in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, types, datetime-format, postgresql-copy

I've exported a CSV file from Excel which has date in format **ddmmyyyy hmm**. I'm using the `COPY` function to import to a table in PostgreSQL.

Since I only want to retain the date part I tried the **`date`** data type:

```
CREATE TABLE Public."ride_details"(ride_id int,created_at date)

COPY Public."ride_details" FROM '/tmp/ride_details.csv' DELIMITER ',' csv HEADER;
```

But that resulted in:

> ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "26/07/19 5:48"
>   HINT:  Perhaps you need a different "datestyle" setting.
>   CONTEXT:  COPY ride_details, line 2, column created_at: "26/07/19 5:48"
>   SQL state: 22008

Do I need to specify a different data type or how to make this work?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter thanks alot, you resolved my query. :D

Comment: Note the added bits!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`COPY` is rather unforgiving with invalid input. (This way it can be fast an reliable.)

It ***may*** be enough to set a matching [`datestyle`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-DATESTYLE) setting:

```
SET datestyle = 'ISO,DMY';  -- DMY being the relevant part
```

... and retry. (Sets the setting for your session only.) Related:

- [Import CSV with timestamp format "dd.mm.yyyy hh.mm.ss" using psql \copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14042452/import-csv-with-timestamp-format-dd-mm-yyyy-hh-mm-ss-using-psql-copy/14042589#14042589)

Info in your question is not entirely clear, you may have to do more:
copy to a temporary "staging" table with a `text` column, and `INSERT` to the actual target table from there using `to_date()` - with a custom pattern specifying your non-standard date format:

```sql
CREATE TABLE public.ride_details(ride_id int,created_at date);  -- target table

CREATE TABLE pg_temp.step1(ride_id int, created_at text);  -- temp staging table

COPY TO pg_temp.step1 ...;

INSERT INTO public.ride_details(ride_id, created_at)
SELECT ride_id, to_date(created_at, 'DD/MM/YY')  -- or whatever
FROM   pg_temp.step1;
```

[`to_date()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-TABLE) ignores dangling characters after the given pattern, so we do not have to deal with your odd `hmm` specification (`hh`?).

I went with the `YY` format displayed in the error msg, not the `yyyy` you claim at the top. Either way, the input must be in ***consistent*** format, or you need to do more, yet ...

All in a **single DB session**, since that's the scope of temp tables. The temp table is not persisted and dies automatically at the end of the session. I use it for performance reasons.

Else you need a plain table as stepping stone, which is persisted across sessions and can be deleted after having served its purpose.

Related:

- [How to ignore errors with psql \copy meta-command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36634360/how-to-ignore-errors-with-psql-copy-meta-command/36635312#36635312)
- [How to update selected rows with values from a CSV file in Postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8910494/how-to-update-selected-rows-with-values-from-a-csv-file-in-postgres/8910810#8910810)